# QListWidget drag externally without item removal?

Tags: python, qt, drag-and-drop, pyqt, pyside

Versions: Qt 4.8.5, PySide 1.2.2, Python 2.7.10, Windows 8.1

I have subclassed `QListWidget` so that I can control drag and drop behavior as needed. Currently it only implements `dropEvent()` and `mimeData()` so that internal reordering of items forces the use of the `MoveAction` type, and so that dragged item text is stored in the `mimeData` when dropped externally.

```
class TestList(QtGui.QListWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestList, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.viewport().setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setDropIndicatorShown(True)

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.source() == self:
            event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
        super(TestList, self).dropEvent(event)

    def mimeData(self, items):
        mime_data = super(TestList, self).mimeData(items)
        mime_data.setText(("\n").join([item.text() for item in items]))
        return mime_data
```

As implemented, a `TestList` can receive `QListWidgetItems` dragged from another list widget and can reorder its own items. Everything works as expected except that whenever items are dragged out of a `TestList` and dropped onto, say, an external text editor, the item gets removed from it.

How do I prevent item removal (i.e., cause `CopyAction` behavior) when dragged out of the `TestList` widget and dropped to some external application (or even to another widget in the same application)? Note that I want to preserve the `MoveAction` behavior when items are dragged around for reordering within the `TestList` widget.

I tried setting the `defaultDropAction` to `CopyAction` but that didn't seem to have any effect. And there is no event method to override when the drop occurs in some other application.

Update: I have noticed that removal of the item seems to mostly (only?) happen when the destination of the drop is a certain type of text editor. Examples include Sublime Text 2 and PyCharm. How is this inconsistency of behavior possible?

I've placed an example python script here:

http://www.jrcooper.com/public/test_list.txt

Change the file extension to .py and just run it through Python at the command line.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Except for self-drops, the items are always copied. This is using Qt-4.8.7 with either PySide-1.2.4 or PyQt-4.11.4 on Linux. Dropping on SublimeText2 makes no difference.

Comment: @ekhumoro: I have a sneaking suspicion this might be a Windows anomaly?

Comment: The example script link returns a 404 (Page not found error)